# EntityFramework DbContext in static method per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

How Entity Framework `DbContext` works in static method per web request? is there any performance issue? I have 2 classes below . Which one is better to use ? or bad? Do we need get instance all pear request ? is there any issue?

```
public class MyClassA 
{
    public static Product GetProduct(int Id) 
    {
        using(MyContext myContext = new MyContext())
        return myContext.Products.Where(x = > x.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}

public class MyClassB 
{
    MyContext myContext = new MyContext()

    public static Product GetProduct(int Id) 
    {
        return myContext.Products.Where(x = > x.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Call in Controller

```
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
{
    public Product GetProductStaticMethodinMyClassA(int Id)
    {
        return MyClassA.GetProduct(Id);
    }

    public Product GetProductStaticMethodinMyClassB(int Id)
    {
        return MyClassB.GetProduct(Id);
    }


    public Product GetProductinRequlurUse(int Id)
    {
        MyContext myContext = new MyContext();

        return myContext.Products.Where(x => x.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`? If you want to encapsulate the `DbContext`, you may consider implement `Repository` instead of `Static Method`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create one `DbContext` per HTTP request... i.e. do not share the same DbContext between multiple requests.

C# Garbage Collector would automatically dispose of `DbContext` once it goes out of scope, so you don't have to put it in a `using` block, but having said that, most people do use `using` block and [MS seems to encourage it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext):

> The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and
>   ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use
>   using if you want all the resources that the context controls to be
>   disposed at the end of the block. When you use using, the compiler
>   automatically creates a try/finally block and calls dispose in the
>   finally block.
>
> ```
> public void UseProducts()
> {
>     using (var context = new ProductContext())
>     {     
>         // Perform data access using the context
>     }
> }
> ```

---

About usage of `DbContext` in your controller, your question is about design and opinion based... if you follow DDD principles, `DbContext` goes into Infrastructure Layer and your Controllers belongs to Presentation Layers... so you would not use `DbContext` directly in the controller at the first place.

If you want to use `DbContext` inside your controller, it is better to inject it, than to initialize it in the controller, initializing `DbContext` inside a controller violates SRP, because it is not controller's concern to initialize `DbContext`.